# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus of a definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \int_{2x}^{3x+1}\! \sin\left(t^4\right)\, \mathrm{d}t$$

could you just use the *Fundamental Theorem of Calculus* to get

$$\sin\left(t^4\right) \bigg|_{2x}^{3x+1}$$

ie

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \int_{2x}^{3x+1} \sin\left(t^4\right)\mathrm{d}t \space =\space \sin\left((3x+1)^4\right)-\sin\left((2x)^4\right)$$

Comment: No, you need to use the chain rule as well.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $F(t)$ be an antiderivative of $\sin(t^4)$.  Then what you have is
$$
\frac{d}{dx}(F(3x+1)-F(2x)).
$$
You can use the chain rule and the fact that $F'(x)=\sin(x^4)$ to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In the most general manner, the fundamental theorem of calculus gives $$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} F (t) \, dt=F \Big(b(x) \Big) b'(x)-F  \Big(a(x) \Big) a'(x)$$